# usage of word better

Tags: modal-verbs, adverbs, future-tense

I want to ask whether the word "Better" be used as adverb preceding the verb in active voice,I mean is the following sentence correct?

> "After doing the IT diploma I may better secure the computer network of our office."

Answer (score 1):

It should be "getting" a diploma, not "doing" a diploma -- a diploma is something you *receive* after *taking* a series of courses -- but otherwise yes, you are on the right track.  For example, here is how "better" is most frequently used in this way:

> I took some network security courses to **better understand** how to prevent hackers from getting into the office system.

Apparently "to better understand" is by far the most common use of this grammar structure, but "to better secure" should be grammatical.  But still unusual, so instead you could say:

> After taking the IT class I may be able to **more effectively secure** the computer office network.

or

> After taking the IT class I may be able to **improve** office network **security**.

Comment: "gettinge" will work, but "earning" would better describe the situation. After all, someone giving you a diploma doesn't make you any smarter. The studying and work you do make you smarter.

Comment: You might mention that using better as an adverb before  the verb tends to make the writer sound more educated.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, in general. However, I'd change a few things about the sentence.

> "After **doing** the IT diploma

You receive/earn a diploma. You DO a program/course.

> I **may** better secure the computer network of our office"

Using **can** is better than may. Or "will be able to"